# different location of AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, ant, android-manifest, manifest

i have a custom buildchain for an android project.
there is a build.xml and build.properties.
build.properties contains this line:

> manifest.file         =${env.WORK_FOLDER}/AndroidManifest.xml

and **WORK_FOLDER** is correctly set to **proj_root_work**.

the layout is like the following:

```
proj_root-_work [DIR] (some stuff gets preprocessed and all finally copied here - src, res, assets and the AndroidManifest.xml)
         -build.xml 
         -build.properties
```

then i call ant for my build configuration from the proj_root
and it complains about not finding *AndroidManifest.xml*. when i put it in  my proj_root it works,
but i really want it in my _Work directory.
i read that the file HAS TO BE in the root, what is the point then of the build.properties entry?
also i saw some custom parameters to aapt.exe ...

any hints welcome, thx

Comment: Why not copying your manifest to the root using ANT before compiling and then remove it when job is complete?

Comment: thx, i've already thought about that. either this or how i do it right now, with a batch script. i just wanted to know if there are other solutions ...

Answer (score 1):

You can give ant instructions to use an alternate AndroidManifest.xml location by using a definition given to aapt during the build, e.g "app_manifest":

```
ant -Dapp_manifest=_Work/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Then, add the following block to build.xml:

```
    <target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
    <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
        <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                command="package"
                versioncode="${version.code}"
                versionname="${version.name}"
                debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                manifest="${app_manifest}"
                assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                androidjar="${android.jar}"
                apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                projectLibrariesResName="project.libraries.res"
                projectLibrariesPackageName="project.libraries.package"
                previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                buildType="${build.target}">
            <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
            <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
            <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
            <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
        </aapt>
    </do-only-if-not-library>
</target>
```

This will resolve "app_manifest" to whatever you give it.

Answer (score 0):

I just simply put

```
<property name="manifest.file" value="AndroidManifest.xml.tmp" />
```

in the build.xml, below this line

```
<property file="local.properties" />
```

and it works well